# How do I use Linq to read XML

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML

```
<Transaction><TransactionID>1559183866</TransactionID><Email>joe@xyz.com</Email><Frequency>Yearly</Frequency><Amount>10</Amount><Status>1</Status><CreateDate>2/7/2012 8:29:43 AM</CreateDate></Transaction>
```

I am trying to use link to create an object to reference the contents

```
XDocument result = XDocument.Load(readStream);

var detail = (from x in result.Descendants("transaction")
              select new {
                  TransactionID = x.Element("transactionid").Value,
                  Frequency = x.Element("frequency").Value,
                  Amount = x.Element("amount").Value,
                  Email = x.Element("email").Value,
                  Status = x.Element("status").Value
              }).First();
```

But keep getting an Exception Sequence contains no Elements.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use Linq to XML enough to be sure, but glancing at this, XML is case-sensitive...  Is LINQ to XML?  Note that the elements are capitalized, and your link query is all lower case.  If case-sensitivity is an issue, then that alone would prevent you finding matches in your query.

Comment: @DavidStratton you're right, you should write it as an answer.

Comment: @DavidStratton I'd convert your comment to an answer... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching elements is a case-sensitive operation.

> eg. "Transaction" != "transaction"

Try this instead:

```
var detail = (from x in result.Descendants("Transaction") 
                          select new { 
                              TransactionID = x.Element("TransactionID").Value, 
                              Frequency =  x.Element("Frequency").Value,
                              Amount = x.Element("Amount").Value, 
                              Email = x.Element("Email").Value,
                              Status = x.Element("Status").Value })
                              .First();
```

Comment: Darn!  You beat me to it!  I finally got my code to work.  +1 for you.

Comment: Sorry for that, did not see your comment!

Comment: No problem.  Like I said, I wasn't sure.  I was only guessing, and you beat me to it fair and square.

Answer (score 4):

If that's the *whole* of the XML, then you're making life more complicated than you need to. The `Transaction` element is the root element, and you *know* there'll be exactly one:

```
XDocument result = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

// Just for brevity
var x = result.Root;
var detail = new {
          // Note the fixed capitalization
          TransactionID = x.Element("TransactionID").Value,
          Frequency = x.Element("Frequency").Value,
          Amount = x.Element("Amount").Value,
          Email = x.Element("Email").Value,
          Status = x.Element("Status").Value
      };
Console.WriteLine(detail);
```

Of course, if this is part of a larger document, then you could use:

```
var x = result.Descendants("Transaction").First();
// Same as before
```

You might want to consider using the explicit conversions from `XElement` to various other types, by the way. For example:

```
var detail = new {
          // Note the fixed capitalization
          TransactionID = (string) x.Element("TransactionID"),
          Frequency = (string) x.Element("Frequency"),
          Amount = (int) x.Element("Amount"),
          Email = (string) x.Element("Email"),
          Status = (int) x.Element("Status")
      };
```

Note that any casts to nullable types (either reference types or nullable value types) will simply return null if the input is null, so a missing element would end up giving you a null result. Sometimes that's a good thing; other times you really want an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Given your XML you should change this line [EDIT: given your XML use Jon's answer]

```
var detail = (from x in result.Descendants("Transaction")
```

to

```
var detail = (from x in result.Element("Transaction")
```

That will prevent any nested Transaction elements to be included in the result. Obviously you've got the casing problem too.